# An best practice example of an MVP implementation of Unit Testing (in VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, mvp

Can anyone point me towards a complete scenario using

MSTest,vb.net, with or without mocks,MVP (supervising controller)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I learned the pattern.  Best practice?  I don't know.  But it includes unit testing examples:

[Design Patterns: Model View Presenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx)

I downloaded the source, and its all C# without a translation to VB.net. Not ideal, but it might get you started.